# Embed PDF using Angular 6 in Edge and Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, pdf, microsoft-edge

I was trying to embed PDF into my angular app with some libraries and so on, but neither of them works in Edge and Internet Explorer and Chrome on mobile as well.All I got is showing buttons open, save, etc.
Can someone explain why is this happening, and if there is a solution for this particular issue here?

Comment: Is Adobe Acrobat Reader installed on the devices?

Comment: Yes, it is, but still, no success.

Comment: The problem was that I was getting source as blob and not like actual link to the document. After I moved it to link and hosted on e.g. sw3 then it was all ok.